# Vue 3 Automatic Update Array Outside Vue App

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a simple scoring app that uses Vue 3 to maintain the scores and totals.  I have a global **teams** object that contains all the scores.  My Vue 3 app updates my scores quite happily within itself, but I also need to access the **teams** object outside of the Vue app to do other non-user interface activities, like saving etc. and i'd like to keep them sync'd.

My global **teams** object looks like this:

```
let teams = [];
teams[0] = {
    players: [
      { name: "Player 1" },
      { name: "Player 2" }
    ],
    scores: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  };
teams[1] = {
    players: [
      { name: "Player 1" },
      { name: "Player 2" }
    ],
    scores: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  };
```

I link it to my Vue 3 app like this:

```
data() {
      return {
        home: teams[0],
        away: teams[1]
      };
    },
```

If I update a score on the **home** or **away** object within Vue, the global **teams** object is not updated.  For example I have a Save function (outside of Vue) that relies on the **teams** object be kept in sync with updates to **home** and **away**.

Is there a way to do this?  Am I going about it all wrong?  I could move my Save function into Vue but I was trying to separate out my user interface logic.  I do have other functions that need access to a sync'd **teams** object and i'd rather not add everything into the Vue app.

Thanks in advance. J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do appear to have found an ugly solution.  I just copy the home and away objects back to the teams object during a Vue 3 update, like this:

```
updated() {
   teams[0] = this.home;
   teams[1] = this.away;
}
```

Although it works, it does seem a bit clunky, as it copies the whole object back rather than just the bit that changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use `computed` getters and setters instead of `data`:

```
computed: {
  home: {
    get() { return teams[0] },
    set(val) { teams[0] = val }
  },
  away: {
    get() { return teams[1] },
    set(val) { teams[1] = val }
  },
}
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks Daniel I'll give it a try.

Comment: I have now tried it but I couldn't get to work.  When I update my input element it doesn't seem to trigger the setter.  Here's my Input element: `<input type="number" v-model="home.scores[0]" />`. The getter does seem to work though.

Comment: Is the setter failing because I have two arrays (players and scores) in each of my teams array?

Comment: The setter is failing because you're not setting the home or away properties, you're setting a nested property. In which case the solution below is probably the best way to go

Comment: Thanks Daniel it seems to be working so far.